# Point on line equidistant from $A$ and $B$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

On the line $l$ find the point equidistant from $A$ and $B$.

$A(3,2,0), \quad B(1,1,1), \quad l : \begin{cases} x = 2t + 1 \\ y = t + 2 \\ z = 2t - 1 \end{cases} t \in \mathbb{R}$

So directional vector is $\vec{l} = [2,1,2]$ and $\vec{AB} = [-2,-1,1]$

This is first time I encounter such task, can someone help me solve it?

Comment: Hint: Consider a point $L(t)$ on the line. Now calculate the distances $|LA|^2$ and $|LB|^2$. We want the distances to be equal, so we want $|LA|= |LB| \Rightarrow |LA|^2 - |LB|^2 = 0 $...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to solve the equation $(2t+1-3)^{2}+(t+2-2)^{2}+(2t-1)^{2} =(2t+1-1)^{2}+(t+2-1)^{2}+(2t-2)^{2}$. When you expand the sqquares you will get $9t^{2}$ on both sides. Once you cancel this you can easily find $t$. Finally you get the desired point $(x,y,z)$ by plugging in the value of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

You started good.

The simplest way to proceed further is considering that the equidistant point shall be on the plane bisecting $AB$ **and** on the line given. So

Find the bisecting plane of the segment $AB$:
 - mid point is ...
 - two normal vectors to segment $AB$ are ..
 - the parametric equation of the bisecting plane (in the parameters $u,v$ different than $t$) is ...

Find the the intersection of the bisecting plane with the given line : three linear equations in three unknowns ...

Comment: @amd: what a lapsus, thanks for signalling !